# Unreal Engine “FParse::HexNumber” How is it working?

Tags: c++, hex, unreal-engine4, unreal-engine5

(0x8877665544332211 >> 8 & 0xffff)

I am trying to convert this operation to hexadecimal, but I have not been successful.

I couldn’t use FParse::HexNumber.

https://docs.unrealengine.com/5.0/en-US/API/Runtime/Core/Misc/FParse/HexNumber64/

Has anyone tried or can help?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
 
int main()
{
    int i = (0x8877665544332211 >> 8 & 0xffff);
 
    std::ostringstream ss;
    ss << std::hex << i;
    std::string result = ss.str();
 
    std::cout << result << std::endl;        // 0x3322
 
    return 0;
}
```

I wrote this code in standard c++, I couldn't run it on Unreal Engine.
I don't understand how FParse::HexNumber works

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "convert this operation to hexadecimal". It is also very unclear how whatever that means is related to parsing a string. (Do you mean the opposite of parsing – creating a string with the hexadecimal representation of 13090?)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with just `0x8877665544332211 >> 8`. One hexadecimal digit represents 4 bits, so 8 bits is two hexadecimal digits. `>>` means shift right, so this much evaluates to `0x88776655443322`.

That gives us: `0x88776655443322 & 0xffff`. As above, one hex digit is 4 bits. 0xf means all four bits are set. So, 0xffff is 16 bits, all set. For some bit `x`, `x & 1 = x`, so this translates to keeping the 16 least significant bits of the left operand, which is: `0x3322`

Comment: I know how it works. But I couldn't do it in unreal engine.

Comment: FParse::HexNumber just reads a number, so it'll convert a string containing `3322` into an integer containing 0x3322. If you're looking for something to parse/interpret the entire expression: `0x8877665544332211 >> 8 & 0xffff`, you'll have to look elsewhere.